# Grid Template Area Issues

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In CSS grid, my container fills the width of the screen but the grid template area does not: is there a fix to this. I have tried to adjust the size of the container, but that just changes the position of the grid. Could this be an issue of using grid template area because this system works with grid-template rows and grid-template columns?

```css
body
{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 0.7vw;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1
{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1200%;
 margin: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}

a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

a:hover
{
 color: #404040;
}

:root 
{
    --color-one: #cccccc; 
 --color-two: #8533ff;
 --color-three: #f2f2f2;
 --text-color: black;
}

/*Navbar*/
.navbar
{
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: var(--color-one);
 font-size: 250%;
 color: var(--text-color);
 opacity: 0.9;
 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 100%;
 grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr 3fr 3fr;
 text-align: center;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.navBarItems
{
 margin-top: 15px;
}

#navBarHead
{
 margin-top: 12.5px;
 font-size: 120%;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.tutorial
{
 display: grid; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 55%;
 grid-template-areas: 
 "a a a a"
 "b c d e"
 "b c d e"
 "b c d e"
 "b c d e";
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: var(--color-two);
}

.topHeader
{
 font-size: 250%;
 color: white;
 vertical-align: center;
 align-self: center;
 
}

.video
{
 background-color: var(--color-three); 
 font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <title>Code !t</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="htmlcss.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="navbar">
   
   <div id = "navBarHead"><a href src="index.html">Code !t</a></div>
   <div class = "navBarItems">HTML</div>
   <div class = "navBarItems">CSS</div>
   <div class = "navBarItems">JAVA SCRIPT</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class = "tutorial">
  <div class = "topHeader" style="grid-area: a">HTML Basics</div>
  <div class = "Video" style="grid-area: b"></div>
  <!--<div class = "Video"></div>
  <div class = "Video"></div>
  <div class = "Video"></div>-->
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove `justify-content: center;`?

Comment: Thanks so much: that fixed the issue